# Is there a similar expression as "elbow grease" in Japanese?

Tags: expressions, idioms

The idiom [elbow grease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_grease), and in French "huile de coude" means that the only thing that is required is putting some manual efforts into an action (scrubbing, washing, mixing...). The term elbow grease was first used in 1672; a 1699 dictionary of slang called it “a derisive word for sweat.”.

For example:

> Avec un peu d'huile de coude, tu peux enlever ces tâches.

> With a bit of elbow grease, you can remove those stains.

It means that the only way to remove the stains is to scrub vividly (not using some kind of grease/oil). Is there a similar idiom/expression in Japanese ?

Comment: I can't think of or find a similar ことわざ, but this also seems to refer to just 苦労/肉体労働/重労働?

Comment: Does it mean something like 力技（ちからわざ）？